# error in web api controller when getting value send from js

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

i am new in angularjs i have a project where some get and post method 
this is my js

```
var app = angular.module('angularTable', []);

app.controller('listdata', function ($scope, $http) {



$scope.joblist = function (Data) {


    $scope.job = [];

    $.ajax({
        url: "/JobApi/getjoblist",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        method: 'GET',
        data: Data,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    }).success(function (response) {

        $scope.$apply(function () {
            debugger;
            if (response != null) {
                $scope.divstateList = false;
                $scope.divjobList = true;
                $scope.job = response;
            }
        });

    })


.error(function (error) {
  alert(error);


});
}

});
```

And this is my web api controller

```
[System.Web.Http.Route("JobApi/getjoblist")]
    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]

    public List<Getjoblist> getjoblist([FromBody]string Data)
    {
        try
        {
            JobBL objbl = new JobBL();
            var joblist = objbl.Citywisejoblist(Convert.ToInt32(Data));
            List<Getjoblist> list = new List<Getjoblist>();
            foreach (var t in joblist)
            {
                Getjoblist GetAll = new Getjoblist();
                GetAll.jobID = Convert.ToInt32(t.ID);
                GetAll.jobtital = t.Title;
                GetAll.jobdescription = t.Description;
                GetAll.jobimage = t.JobImage;
                list.Add(GetAll);

            }
            return list;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }


    }
```

not getting the value in controller send from js how to solve the problem please help me

Comment: Angular? You're doing it wrong !

Comment: There is so much wrong, I'm not sure where to begin.  First, post your full api controller code so that people can see it.  What is the name of your api Controller?  Second, you don't use $.ajax in your Angular controller. Third, I would create a service for api calls since you are using MVC, and fourth, you should return a json object.